# iOS Swift Add SVG Image to button like Android

Tags: android, ios, swift, image, svg

In Android, we can import SVG as Vector XML,
Use this as Drawable,
Change colors of SVG Icons and add to button

```
void setSvgIcnForBtnFnc(Button setBtnVar, int setSvgVar, int setClrVar, String PosVar)
{
    Drawable DevDmjVar = getDrawable(setSvgVar);
    DevDmjVar.setBounds(0,0,Dpx24,Dpx24);
    DevDmjVar.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(setClrVar, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    switch (PosVar)
    {
        case "Tit" : setBtnVar.setCompoundDrawables(null, DevDmjVar, null, null); break;
        case "Rit" : setBtnVar.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, DevDmjVar, null); break;
        case "Pit" : setBtnVar.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, null, DevDmjVar); break;
        default: setBtnVar.setCompoundDrawables(DevDmjVar, null, null, null); break;
    }
}
```

How do I do this in swift for iphones ?

```
setBtnVar.setImage(<image: UIImage?>, forState: <UIControlState>)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**UPD**: Also see this [UseYourLoaf blog post](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/xcode-9-vector-images/)

Just found on [Erica Sadun blog post](http://ericasadun.com/2017/06/15/the-unexpected-joy-of-vector-images-in-ios-11/) that on **iOS 11** you [could use Vector Assets](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017-201/?time=2046).

What "Vector Assets" mean:

> If you click that box, the vector data will be shipped with your
>   application. Which, on the one hand, makes your application a little
>   bit larger, because the vector data takes up some space. But on the
>   other hand, will give you the opportunity to scale these images, which
>   might be useful in a number of different situations. So, one is, if
>   you know that this particular image is going to be used at multiple
>   sizes. But that might be less obvious. So, one case is a symbolic
>   glyph that should resize with dynamic type. Since we're thinking about
>   dynamic type, you should also be thinking about having glyphs that are
>   appearing next to type resize appropriately. Another case that's
>   really not obvious, is tab bar images.
>   ... there's a really great accessibility feature that we strongly
>   recommend supporting, that allows for user that have turned their
>   dynamic type size up. ... So, we really recommend doing that to increase the usability of your app across all users

How to use:

1. Convert your SVG file into PDF, e.g. on [ZamZar.com](http://www.zamzar.com)
2. Add your pdf to `Assets.xcassets`

   - Click "Preserve Vector Data" for the imported pdf.
3. Create `UIImageView` in your `UIViewController` and assign pdf file like `UIImage`.

**or** [Asset Catalog Creator](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/asset-catalog-creator-pro/id809625456?mt=12) available in the Mac App Store will do steps 1 and 2 with a simple drag and drop.

---

**iOS < 11**

There is no native way to use SVG image.

Take a look at [Macaw](https://github.com/exyte/Macaw)

Import framework via [Cocoapod](http://cocoapods.org)

```
pod "Macaw", "0.8.2"
```

Check their [example project](https://github.com/exyte/Macaw/tree/master/Example/Example): this is how you render `tiger.svg` (located in project directory, not in an `Assets.xcassets` file)

```
import UIKit
import Macaw

class SVGExampleView: MacawView {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(node: SVGParser.parse(path: "tiger"), coder: aDecoder)
    }

}
```

---

There are some other third-party libraries of course:

- [SwiftSVG](https://github.com/mchoe/SwiftSVG)
- [Snowflake](https://github.com/onmyway133/Snowflake)
- [SVGKit](https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit) Objective-C framework

Comment: Just a note: iOS11 apparently supports vectors (I will assume as pdfs) without rendering them to images first. It may be worthwhile to find a way to convert them to your workflow if there will be a lot of them.

Answer (score 3):

After a nightmare I came up with this solution for using SVG in button using Swift.
This is for all who dont wish to struggle like me

I used the simple [SwiftSVG](https://github.com/mchoe/SwiftSVG) library for getting UIView from SVG File

Usage :

```
namBtnVar.setSvgImgFnc("ikn_sev", ClrVar: UIColor.cyanColor())
```

Install [SwiftSVG](https://github.com/mchoe/SwiftSVG) Library

1) Use pod to install :

// For Swift 3

```
pod 'SwiftSVG'
```

// For Swift 2.3

```
pod 'SwiftSVG', '1.1.5'
```

2) Add framework

> Goto AppSettings
>       -> General Tab
>       -> Scroll down to Linked Frameworks and Libraries
>       -> Click on plus icon
>       -> Select SVG.framework

3) Add below code anywhere in your project

```
extension UIButton
{
    func setSvgImgFnc(svgImjFileNameVar: String, ClrVar: UIColor)
    {
        setImage((getSvgImgFnc(svgImjFileNameVar, ClrVar : ClrVar)), forState: .Normal)
    }
}

func getSvgImgFnc(svgImjFileNameVar: String, ClrVar: UIColor) -> UIImage
{
    let svgURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(svgImjFileNameVar, withExtension: "svg")
    let svgVyuVar = UIView(SVGURL: svgURL!)

    /* The width, height and viewPort are set to 100 

        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            width="100%" height="100%"
            viewBox="0 0 100 100">

        So we need to set UIView Rect also same
    */

    svgVyuVar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
    for svgVyuLyrIdx in svgVyuVar.layer.sublayers!
    {
        for subSvgVyuLyrIdx in svgVyuLyrIdx.sublayers!
        {
            if(subSvgVyuLyrIdx.isKindOfClass(CAShapeLayer))
            {
                let SvgShpLyrIdx = subSvgVyuLyrIdx as? CAShapeLayer
                SvgShpLyrIdx!.fillColor = ClrVar.CGColor
            }
        }
    }
    return svgVyuVar.getImgFromVyuFnc()
}

extension UIView
{
    func getImgFromVyuFnc() -> UIImage
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size)

        self.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image!
    }
}
```

Comment: I should thank @Aleksey Potapov for his hint and suggestion, so I cud come up with this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use vector-based PDFs natively if you select **Single Scale** for **Scale Factors** after importing.

The dimensions of the PDF will be the **1x** dimensions for the asset.

Xcode will generate the rasterized image for every scale. You can then use it like any other image.

Answer (score 0):

I used Aleksey Potapov's answer. The conversion and everything is perfect!
However I had an issue where my image was too large for my application.

So use this to resize it to a good size for ios development:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="30" width="30" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out my app: [Speculid](https://speculid.com)
It will automatically convert SVGs into PDFs or PNGs depending on how your asset library is setup.